# Is there an $\infty$-category of spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

*Disclaimer:* $\infty = (\infty,1)$.

For some time, I have carried this paradigm that there should be an $\infty$-category of $\text{Top}$ whose

- Objects are spaces.
- Morphisms are continuous functions.
- 2-morphisms are homotopies of morphisms.
- 3-morphisms are homotopies of homotopies, etc.

The homotopy category of $\text{Top}$ would be the ordinary category of spaces modulo homotopies.

I figure one way of capturing this idea by more or less waving hands is by showing that $\infty\text{Gpd}$  is precisely the category of Kan complexes, which in turn correspond to ordinary $\text{Top}$ in a Quillen equivalent way. Then in the homotopical context $\infty\text{Gpd} = \text{Top}$. I'm really shy of this approach because I have no idea how the model structures interact with the $\infty$-language.

Another option (described for instance [here](http://www.math.titech.ac.jp/%7Eshanekelly/InfinityCategories2017SS.html#x1-19000XI)), is to take $\text{Top}$ as the nerve of ordinary $\text{Top}$.
The final result, as presented in the link, looks a little like what I conjectured, but I'm not sure.

> *Is this the correct approach to an $\infty$-category of spaces? Can we write a direct definition, as a quasicategory?*

Comment: You need to be a little careful to end up with $\infty$-groupoids; either you restrict attention to CW complexes or you localize at weak equivalences, whatever lets you ignore objects like the Cantor set.

Comment: Infinity category means many things. Some define it as a category with topologized Hom spaces. Then spaces are easily seen to form an infinity category.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sure, by Top I think I mean a convenient category like compactly generated

Comment: @ConnorMalin True. I'm thinking about quasicategories.

Comment: Fortunately, they are equivalent notions though it’s a bit of a long route. You essentially cook up a simplicial set with a vertex for every object in the topological category and then make a quasicategory so the hom simplicial sets are the singular sets of the hom spaces.

Comment: @DanielPlácido The Cantor set is a compact Hausdorff space, so you can't avoid it like that. As Qiaochu says, either you throw away the bad objects from your topologically enriched category, or you carry out a localisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* by a space I mean a CW complex.

The $\infty$-category of spaces is usually defined by
$$
\mathbb RN_\Delta(L^H(\text{Kan})),
$$
where

- $L^H(\text{Kan})$ is the DK localization of Kan complexes at weak equivalences.
- $\mathbb RN_\Delta$ is the right derived functor of the homotopy coherent nerve.

This is indeed a quasi-category from the Joyal-Bergner structures Quillen equivalence.

Also $\text{Sing}:\text{CW}\to\text{Kan}$ will take a continous function $X\to Y$ to an $\infty$-functor between $\infty$-fundamental grupoids $\text{Sing}(X)\to\text{Sing}(Y)$ .